# Swing JTable with custom TableCellRenderer

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

In my java application I want to set the color and also the behavior when it is selected. For this I wrote a custom implementation of the TableCellRenderer and it is working as I want. But there is something I'm still confused about...

Here is the implementation of the `TableCellRenderer`:

```
public class AccountMovementTableCellRenderer extends JLabel implements TableCellRenderer{
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean  isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column){     
        //My implementation here...
        return this;
    }
}
```

And here the creation of the `JTable`:

```
AccountMovementTableCellRenderer accountMovementCellRenderer = new AccountMovementTableCellRenderer();
entryTable = new JTable(entryModel){
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public TableCellRenderer getCellRenderer(int row, int column){
        return accountMovementCellRenderer;
    }
};
```

I create only one instance of my CellRenderer but I was expecting one CellRenderer per cell and I was surprised it is working this way... The content and color is for every cell different but it uses always the same instance of the CellRenderer, so how could this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Component that `TableCellRenderer.prepareRenderer` returns is reused to render the contents of the `JTable` - in your case your renderer extends `JLabel` (you can could have just extended `DefaultTableCellRenderer`) - this  JLabel is used to paint the contents of the `JTable`. The `prepareRenderer` method is used to customize the JLabel for each cell before rendering. To quote [Oracle's tutorial on the JTables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

> You might expect each cell in a table to be a component. However, for performance reasons, Swing tables are implemented differently.
>
> Instead, a single cell renderer is generally used to draw all of the cells that contain the same type of data. You can think of the renderer as a configurable ink stamp that the table uses to stamp appropriately formatted data onto each cell. When the user starts to edit a cell's data, a cell editor takes over the cell, controlling the cell's editing behavior.

Answer (score 2):

The single renderer instance creates a unique *image* of itself for each cell with each image reflecting the state of that cell based on your code above.