# Adding CheckBox and Button in Table

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox, jcheckbox

1. I am trying to add separated column for button where every row will have have button and on click of the button color of the row should change
2. I am also trying to add checkbox column for every row
3. And at last a submit button, below table which on click will show the pop of selected row via checkbox

I can't think of logic of the problem.

My code is below

```
public class Main {
    private static final JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        jFrame.setSize(350,200);
        jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jFrame.add(panel);
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        JComboBox<String> cb = new JComboBox<>(new String[] {"","Show","Hide"});
        panel.add(cb);
        JButton button = new JButton("change");
        button.setBounds(10,80,80,25);
        panel.add(button);

        String[][] rec = {
                { "1", "Steve", "AUS" },
                { "2", "Virat", "IND" },
                { "3", "Kane", "NZ" },
                { "4", "David", "AUS" },
                { "5", "Ben", "ENG" },
                { "6", "Eion", "ENG" },
        };

        String[] header = { "Rank", "Player", "Country" };
        JTable table = new JTable(rec, header);
        panel.add(new JScrollPane(table));
        table.setVisible(false);
        cb.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                    //  YourType varName = (YourType)comboBox.getSelectedItem();`
                    String value = cb.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    if ("Show".equalsIgnoreCase(value)) {
                        table.setVisible(true);
                    }
                    else {
                        table.setVisible(false);
                    }
                }
            }

        });
        jFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I am done implementing checkBox in the table but can't think of How to add button in this

```
public class MyTable extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //initialize Jframe
                MyTable form = new MyTable();
                form.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    public MyTable(){
        //the form
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(200,200,800,300);
        setTitle("Form");
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        //add scroll pane
        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane();
        pane.setBounds(70,80,600,200);
        getContentPane().add(pane);

        //the table
        final JTable table = new JTable();
        pane.setViewportView(table);

        //the model of table
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(){
            public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column){
                switch (column){
                    case 0:
                        return String.class;
                    case 1:
                        return String.class;
                    case 2:
                        return String.class;
                    case 3:
                        return String.class;
                    case 4:
                        return Boolean.class;
                    default:
                        return String.class;
                }
            }
        };
        // setting model of the table
        table.setModel(model);
        model.addColumn("Points");
        model.addColumn("Position");
        model.addColumn("Team");
        model.addColumn("Manager");
        model.addColumn("Select");

        for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
            model.addRow(new Object[0]);
            model.setValueAt("Column 3",i,0);
            model.setValueAt("Our Row"+(i+1),i,1);
            model.setValueAt("Column 2",i,2);
            model.setValueAt("Column 4",i,3);
            model.setValueAt(false,i,4);
        }

        //obtain selected
        JButton button = new JButton("Submit");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //get selected item
                for(int i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++){
                    Boolean checked = Boolean.valueOf(table.getValueAt(i,4).toString());
                    String col = table.getValueAt(i,1).toString();

                    //Display
                    if(checked){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,col);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        // Add button to form
        button.setBounds(20,30,130,30);
        getContentPane().add(button);
    }
}
```

Thanks! I am stuck in this for few days, does anyone know how to implement this.

Comment: See: [Table Button Column](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/) for a renderer/editor for a button.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to place a JCheckBox in a JTable is a TableModel that has a boolean value in one of the columns (see [TableModel.getColumnClass()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html#getColumnClass(int)))

To get both a JCheckBox and a JButton into one cell create your custom [TableCellRenderer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/table/TableCellRenderer.html). See also [Swing JTable with custom TableCellRenderer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39153879/swing-jtable-with-custom-tablecellrenderer)

Comment: can you show how to do it, in above example ?

Comment: Mind checking the Oracle tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer

Comment: don't add components as data ..

Comment: I have added the check box feature! can anyone tell me how can I add Button feature mentioned in the question ??

Comment: A renderer only allows you to display text as a button it does not provide to click on the button and invoke an action. I added a comment providing a link to a solution that provides the renderer/editor for a button.